# Barcode to Product Name Converter

Tags: c#, barcode

We are designing a mobile shopping system.
The camera on the phone will read the barcode and then we have to convert the barcode to a standard product name in order to save it to our database.

We are saving it to our database because we are connecting to a web service of local e-commerce sites to get their price about the related product. We are sending the product name to get the price from them, so that the user can see the prices, compare and buy.

We cannot send barcode number to get the data from the e-commerce sites because some sites do not have the info of the barcode number.

I have to somehow get the product name by only knowing the barcode. Google returns the result when barcode number is searched. But how am I going to parse the data? or how am I going to know which answer of google search best suits my input?

Is there a site that sells barcode and product name data match?

We are designing the system with C#

Thanks alot.

Comment: There's almost a request for the product to be written for you hidden in there!  What have you actually done so far?  Just googling "barcode reading web service" returns several possible candidates for code, software and services

Comment: I googled most of the keywords. Google returns me the product name if i search the barcode. But there are many results and many websites in google answers. I cannot know which web site to go and get the product name and do that programmatically and fill my database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a "UPC lookup" website.  Try googling for "UPC lookup".  There are lots of possibilities like [upcdatabase.com](http://www.upcdatabase.com/).

Comment: Thanks alot, this enlightened me alot

Answer (score 0):

I've had pretty good luck using https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/. I believe you can look at how the barcode scanning app Zxing uses it @ [Android Bar Code results from lookup into app ZXing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363555/android-bar-code-results-from-lookup-into-app-zxing)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of searching Google's general web index, search [Google Shopping](http://www.google.com/prdhp?hl=en&tab=wf#t:0) or amazon.

Comment: Google shopping returns no record when you try to sarch barcode number. Amazon also does not return any value