# Android Bar Code results from lookup into app ZXing

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, zxing

I am trying to write an app that uses the ZXing bar code scanner app.  I have made the app use the intent for the results.  I get the UPC Code and the UPC type returned which is cool.

If I use the scanner app by itself, rather than linked from my app, the scanner does a lookup and returns all kinds of info from google product search.

As the scanner app already does this, is there a way to get that same data back into my app?

I am not that knowledgeable with Android and Java yet, so if anyone has a way to do this please give me enough info so I can make it work.

thank you!

Comment: Have you asked on http://groups.google.com/group/zxing?

Answer (score 0):

It is accessing Google Product search directly. You can look into its source code at http://code.google.com/p/zxing, under `android/`, to see what it does.